# ffmpeg-php permission denied on localhost

Tags: php, ffmpeg, localhost, permission-denied

I am very new to php. I recently setup php on my mac and I am trying to setup ffmpeg-php to convert various videos to flv or other formats as desired.  I used this tutorial [FFmpeg Mac Installation](http://webrelatedstuff.com/articles/mac-server-setup/ffmpeg-mac-installation/6) and I got ffmpeg to work using the terminal, however, when I try to encode a movie using php I get an error. In my apache error_log file it says permission denied next to the flv file (shown below).

> FFmpeg version 0.6, Copyright (c)
>   2000-2010 the FFmpeg developers
>   built on Dec 30 2010 08:36:24 with gcc
>   4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646) (dot 1)   configuration: --prefix=/usr/local
>   --enable-shared --disable-mmx --enable-libmp3lame --enable-gpl --enable-libfaad --enable-zlib --enable-libvorbis --enable-libfaac --enable-nonfree
>
> libavutil     50.15. 1 / 50.15.
>   1
>    libavcodec    52.72. 2 /
>   52.72. 2
>    libavformat   52.64. 2 / 52.64. 2
>    libavdevice   52. 2.
>   0 / 52. 2. 0
>    libswscale   0.11. 0 /  0.11. 0 
>  Seems stream 1 codec frame rate differs from
>   container frame rate: 1200.00 (1200/1)
>   -> 30.00 (30/1)
>  Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from
>   '/Users/myApple/Sites/AdHere/test.mov':
>   Metadata:
>       major_brand     : qt  
>       minor_version   : 537199360
>       compatible_brands: qt  
>    Duration: 00:00:02.04, start:
>   0.000000, bitrate: 1109 kb/s
>       Stream #0.0(eng): Audio: aac, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 97 kb/s
>       Stream #0.1(eng): Video: h264, yuv420p, 640x480, 1027 kb/s, 30.15
>   fps, 30 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc
>   /Users/myApple/Sites/AdHere/movteststuff.flv:
>   Permission denied

I have no idea what the problem is. I am using the following php code:

```
<?php 
extension_loaded('ffmpeg') or die('Error in loading ffmpeg');

$ffmpegInstance = new ffmpeg_movie('test.AVI');
echo "getDuration: " . $ffmpegInstance->getDuration() .
"<br>getFrameCount: " . $ffmpegInstance->getFrameCount() .
"<br>getFrameRate: " . $ffmpegInstance->getFrameRate() .
"<br>getFilename: " . $ffmpegInstance->getFilename() .
"<br>getComment: " . $ffmpegInstance->getComment() .
"<br>getTitle: " . $ffmpegInstance->getTitle() .
"<br>getAuthor: " . $ffmpegInstance->getAuthor() .
"<br>getCopyright: " . $ffmpegInstance->getCopyright() .
"<br>getArtist: " . $ffmpegInstance->getArtist() .
"<br>getGenre: " . $ffmpegInstance->getGenre() .
"<br>getTrackNumber: " . $ffmpegInstance->getTrackNumber() .
"<br>getYear: " . $ffmpegInstance->getYear() .
"<br>getFrameHeight: " . $ffmpegInstance->getFrameHeight() .
"<br>getFrameWidth: " . $ffmpegInstance->getFrameWidth() .
"<br>getPixelFormat: " . $ffmpegInstance->getPixelFormat() .
"<br>getBitRate: " . $ffmpegInstance->getBitRate() .
"<br>getVideoBitRate: " . $ffmpegInstance->getVideoBitRate() .
"<br>getAudioBitRate: " . $ffmpegInstance->getAudioBitRate() .
"<br>getAudioSampleRate: " . $ffmpegInstance->getAudioSampleRate() .
"<br>getVideoCodec: " . $ffmpegInstance->getVideoCodec() .
"<br>getAudioCodec: " . $ffmpegInstance->getAudioCodec() .
"<br>getAudioChannels: " . $ffmpegInstance->getAudioChannels() .
"<br>hasAudio: " . $ffmpegInstance->hasAudio();

exec('ffmpeg -i /Users/myApple/Sites/AdHere/test.mov /Users/myApple/Sites/AdHere/movteststuff.flv');



?>
```

I am able to see various parameters like filename, frameheight, framewidth, which leads me to believe that ffmpeg-php is kind of working, but maybe I am just doing something wrong in the exec() command.  Anyone have any ideas.  I have been struggling with setting up ffmpeg for quite some time now.

Thanks!

-Jon

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the user that PHP is running as does not have write access to the directory in question. Check the permission of the destination directory and make sure it matches whatever user is executing the PHP script.

Comment: Wow, I think that was it.  You are awesome!

Answer (score 0):

It's just permissions issue...

Make ffmpeg as 777 permission.